# php login will not let me in eventhough user exist in database

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi i can't login to my site and i changed the user name and password manually in database php myadmin.  Any help would be appreciated. and when i try to "forget password, i get no record found even though i have an email in the database.  Here is the code

```
// call when login form submits
     function submitted(){
        $userName=$_POST['userName'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $login=new loginDAO();
        $user=$login->getUser($userName, $password);
        if(empty($user)){
            $message="Invalid User Name or password";
            $this->registry->template->message=$message;
            $this->registry->template->show('login/index');
        }
        if($user['ustype']=='corporateAdmin'){
             $companyInfo=$login->getCompanyDetail($user['uscompanyid']);
             $_SESSION['companyInfo']=$companyInfo;
             $_SESSION['user']=$user;
             $_SESSION['corporateInfo']=$login->getCorporateDetail($user['uscorporateid']);
               if($companyInfo['compstatus']==0&&$_SESSION['corporateInfo']['status']==0){
                   header("location:?rt=".$_SESSION['user']['ustype']."/index");
                   }
               else {
                   session_destroy();
                   unset($_SESSION);
                   header ("location:?rt=login/error/1");
               }
        }
        if($user['ustype']=='superAdmin'){
            $_SESSION['user']=$user;
            header("location:?rt=superAdmin/index");
        }
        else
            if($user['ustype']=='companyAdmin'){
                $companyInfo=$login->getCompanyDetail($user['uscompanyid']);
                //print_r($companyInfo);exit;
                $_SESSION['companyInfo']=$companyInfo;
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                if($companyInfo['compdeleted']==0)
                   header("location:?rt=".$_SESSION['user']['ustype']."/index");
               else {
                   session_destroy();
                   unset($_SESSION);
                   header ("location:?rt=login/error/1");
               }
            }
            else{
                $table=$user['ustype'];
                $userId=$user['usid'];
                $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                $_SESSION['permissions']=$login->getPermissions($userId,$table);
                $companyInfo=$login->getCompanyDetail($user['uscompanyid']);
                //echo "Hi after company".$user['ustype'];exit;
                $_SESSION['companyInfo']=$companyInfo;
                if($companyInfo['compdeleted']==0)
                   header("location:?rt=".$_SESSION['user']['ustype']."/index");
               else {
                   session_destroy();
                   unset($_SESSION);
                   header ("location:?rt=login/error/0");
               }
            }
    }
    function logout(){
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION);
        header("location:?rt=index/index");
    }
    function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
       $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
       $randomString = '';
         for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
         }
       return $randomString;
}
    function forgotPassword(){
       $login=new loginDAO();
       $userName=$_POST['userName'];
       $user= $login->getForgotUser($userName); 
       if(empty($user)){
           echo "No record found";
       }
       else{
           $password=$this->generateRandomString(11);
           $login->changePassword($userName,$password);
           $this->sendEmail($user['usemail'], "Your new Password is = ".$password);
           echo "Your new password is send to your email address. please check your email.";
       }
    }
    function fancy(){
        $this->registry->template->show("login/fancy");
    }
    function error(){
        $this->registry->template->show("companyAdmin/error");
    }
    function checkUserName(){
        $userName=$_REQUEST['userName'];
        $login=new loginDAO();
        echo $login->checkUserName($userName);
    }
    function checkDriverUserName(){
        $userName=$_REQUEST['userName'];
        $login=new loginDAO();
        echo $login->checkDriverUserName($userName);
    } 

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must make an forget form and check the data using email then you can easily change the password.

Comment: i was using the wrong url.  i was just recently hacked and cant get a hold of my developer.  now just realized the site was deleted in the hack and i didnt have a backup.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: you need to cpanel help